# Current sense circuit: small current

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, ltspice, current-measurement

I simulated a current sensing circuit below. I understand Ohm's law and how I have 476 mA throughout my circuit.

What I do not understand is how I have such small current values going into R2 and R3 as well as across my capacitor.

Could anyone explain why those current values are so small in comparison?

[image: Current Sense]

Comment: I believe part of your trouble understanding why the current values are the way they are might be due to how you drew the circuit as a convoluted mess.  [Here is how I drew the same circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY3JM.png).  Does it help any?

Answer (score 2):

The values look correct based on Ohm's law. Your circuit just applies 1 mV across the shunt resistor, resulting in 476 mA, and that voltage is imposed on a load of 1.002 MegOhms, which results in some picoamps of current. 1 mV through 1.002 MegOhms is 998 pA. If you want to model a real world high side current sense circuit you should inject a current through the shunt,or use a voltage like 48 VDC into a 100 ohm load resistor.

Comment: Further, to address the question regarding the capacitor, that particular answer can be found in the `.OPTIONS -- Set Simulator Options` section of the LTspice help under the option `gfarad`.